# How to add encryption certificate for wordpress with wildcard subsites

Tags: wordpress, ssl-certificate

I have a [wordpress installation](http://heart4children.org) and I have a security certificate installed for the main site, however, it is a [subsite installation](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/#wildcard-subdomains) and how do I make the security certificate work for all the wildcard (*) subsites?

Comment: Ask on the stack exchange site dedicated to WordPress

Comment: You need a wildcard SSL certificate, which will cover all sub domains. It's not specific to WordPress, so I don't think it's a suitable questions for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For securing sub domains of the main domain you will have to enable wildcard ssl certificate at only main domain name.

**For example:**

If you have domain name xyz.com and want to secure its all sub domain names then you will have to enable wildcard ssl certificate at *.xyz.com then it will automatically will secure its all first level sub domains like blog.xyz.com, payment.xyz.com etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per you requirements, you need to obtain a new Wildcard SSL certificate to protect your subsites (sub-domains). It will protect your entire website and its multiple sub-domains. To obtain this certificate, you have to add a single asterisk (*) just before your domain name (i.e. - `*.yoursite.com`), it will allow to secure all first-level sub-domains.

As you mentioned that you already have an SSL certificate for your main website, but managing individual certificates for your main site and each sub-domain will be horrible and time consuming for administrators. Wildcard SSL certificate is perfect, flexible and money saving certificate in the state of sub-domains security.